# How to bind TextBox Textchanghe Event To a Command?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

How to bind TextBox Textchanghe Event To a Command...

i want to  changh my Textbox.text whenever my  search method raised

Comment: Please read your question yourself. After that, please correct it.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth please consider hat not all users use English as their first language! To M.Azad, please try to be more specific to give other users a chance to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a behavior called `EventToCommand` in the MVVM Light toolkit. You can use it to bind any event to a `ICommand`.
See [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) and [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/13/bug-correction-in-messenger-and-new-feature-in-eventtocommand-mvvm.aspx).

Comment: what if idont want to use mvvmlighttoolkit what about pure mvvm?

Comment: You tagged your question with mvvm-light so I assumed you were using this framework. Isn't this the case?